# Python code for splitting JPEG's to three separate (R,G,B) FITS images not working anymore

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have a short script called 'split-jpeg-to-fits.py' (from http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/generated/examples/io/split-jpeg-to-fits.html)
it converts a jpg into 3 ('red', 'blue' and 'green') greyscale FITS files.

In Python 3.6 it worked, it was working fine just a few days ago, but not now for some reason, it doesn't even recognize PIL, I get the error 'No module named 'PIL'', so I tried it with Python 2.7.. seems to be OK with PIL/pillow but still doesn't produce results.

Could it be related to me installing Intel Distribution for Python and Miniconda today(?)

All it does (in 2.7) is display the image dimensions and then I get the following error messages, which is indicating a problem with matplotlib:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marti\Downloads\split-jpeg-to-fits.py", line 40, in 
  <module>
  plt.imshow(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3101, in 
  imshow
  **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1717, in 
  inner
  return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5127, 
  in imshow
  im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 607, in 
  set_data
  raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
  TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

and when I close the Python shell I get a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error -

[image]

Any help'd be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved.
Not sure *exactly* why things went wrong, but I uninstalled pillow; physically removed any site packages named 'PIL' or 'Pillow..' (from Py2.7 & 3.6 /Lib/site-packages)... which I HAD done before , to no avail.

Did a 'pip3 install image', pip installed a cached Pillow-5.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl  and now i have a fully functioning script with no errors and perfect results.